# Seatbelt must be retracted after pulling it as far as it will come out

Tags: honda, odyssey, seat-belt

I have a new 2018 Odyssey with about 700 miles on it.  I tested 6 seat belts for a problem I'm having.  4/6 of them must be 100% retracted when you pull the seatbelt out as far as it will go.  In other words, the seat belt will no longer extract until it has been retracted to starting position.  The front 2 seat belts do not exhibit this behavior.  Only the back 4 that I tested.

I took the car to the dealer and they said the issue is with my car seat, however I am able to reproduce this problem with and without car seats installed.  Is this normal for this particular vehicle?

[Please see video for more detail.](https://youtu.be/QwlFwg9L_Lc)

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is. Are you saying that you have to pull out the seat belt all they way out before it starts to go back inside on it's own?

Comment: @rana - updated with video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a normal safety feature.

Most common reason is for child seats. this allows you to lock the belt and pull it tight.

EDIT: It is also not that a child seat triggers this behavior, but that its a feature to allow the safe installation of a child seat.

Edit 2: You may want to look into a seat belt extension to aid with your particular issue (belt isnt long enough for a child to easily engage and disengage on their own without locking the belt)

here is a link I found to a reseller
http://www.seatbeltextenderpros.com/extenders-by-car/

Comment: The issue I have with this feature is with large side impact booster seats. On these you use the normal seat belt.but the kid has to pull the seatbelt almost all the way out to buckle it in.  And if they do they're going to have to take the seatbelt out of the car seat and put it back into the car. Not an easy thing for a seven-year-old

Comment: I see what you mean, but that would be as the dealer said, an issue with the chosen car seat being too large. It may be that the model car you have has a shorter than typical seatbelt.

But all vehicles have seat belts that lock when fully drawn in the rear seats. you would want

Comment: I added an additional edit above as well